# Calendar application - outputting days of the month

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, date, calendar

I'm working on a calendar/planner application and I need some advice.

I'm working on the following part of my application:

[image: days of the month]

It shows the days of the month from 1 till the end of the month, 28/29, 30 or 31. I achieved this.. ([here](http://www.obscura-design.be/planner)) but my code is extremely ugly and I'm sure there must be another way to do this.

I'm working in CodeIgniter. My controller contains the following function to populate the list with the days of the month:

```
    public function init_days()
{
            // post values? in case of previous/next months (ajax)
    if($this->input->post('post_month') && $this->input->post('post_year'))
    {
        $month = $this->input->post('post_month');
        $year = $this->input->post('post_year');
        $data = $this->planner_model->calendar_data($month, $year);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->planner_model->calendar_data();
    }

    // init empty calendar
    $data['calendar'] = '';

    // easy var names
    $current_month = $data['current_month'];
    $current_year = $data['current_year'];

    // echo list into $data['calendar']
    for($i = 1; $i <= $data['days_in_month']; $i++)
    {
        if($current_month == date('n') && $current_year == date('Y'))
        {
            if($i < $data['current_day_of_month'])
            {
                $data['calendar'] .= "<li class='prev_month' value='$i'>$i</li>";
            }
            if($i == $data['current_day_of_month'])
            {
                $data['calendar'] .= "<li class='today' value='$i'>$i</li>";
            }
            if($i > $data['current_day_of_month'])
            {
                $data['calendar'] .= "<li class='next_month' value='$i'>$i</li>";
            }
        }
        if( ($current_month > date('n') && $current_year == date('Y')) || ($current_year > date('Y')) )
        {
            $data['calendar'] .= "<li class='next_month' value='$i'>$i</li>";
        }
        if( ($current_month < date('n') && $current_year == date('Y')) || ($current_year < date('Y')) )
        {
            $data['calendar'] .= "<li class='prev_month' value='$i'>$i</li>";
        }
    }
    $data['month_name'] = ucfirst($this->get_month_name($current_month));

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My model returns the $data array that gets called by the controller (in the else clause, first part):

```
    public function calendar_data($month = '', $year = '')
{
    if( ! empty($month) && ! empty($year))
    {
        $data['current_year'] = $year;
        $data['current_month'] = $month;
        $data['current_day_of_month'] = date('j');
        $data['current_day_of_week'] = date('w');
        $data['days_in_month'] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['current_year'] = date('Y');
        $data['current_month'] = date('n');
        $data['current_day_of_month'] = date('j');
        $data['current_day_of_week'] = date('w');
        $data['days_in_month'] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $data['current_month'], $data['current_year']);
    }


    return $data;
}
```

I then output this in my view with an AJAX call on $(document).ready.

`$("#day_list").html(data['calendar']).fadeIn();`

I'm not happy with the code. It's a mess, and I'm fairly sure I'm breaking MVC here; aren't I? Could someone perhaps give some advice or insights on how to do this in a 'better' way? Thanks a lot.

The full source is [here](https://github.com/cabaret/Studieplanner) in case anyone would be kind enough to look through it and tell me if there's other stuff I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with MVC and the web is you can never really have clear delineation between the view and the controller. That's just the inherent nature of the web. I am more of a CakePHP guy, but the principles are the same. When I write my code, I always ask myself a handful of questions to know the best place to put my code.

1. Am I retrieving, storing, or
   manipulating data? (if so, it's
   model)
2. Am I displaying data or presenting
   data to the end-user? (if so, it's
   view).
3. Everything else goes into my
   controller.

That being said, with only taking a quick look at your code, it appears you are combing model code and view code in the controller, and that is why you feel uneasy about it. Here is some simple logic that may help you:

Move all of the code that builds the list of dates into the model. Call it something like:

```
function create_date_list() {
  // code here
}
```

This will only build an array of the dates you want to display. Keep in mind you can also pass things on the array like whether or not the date is a holiday, current day, weekend, etc. This will help you determine in the view how to format the date without having to add code to the view to do so. So for example, you may have an array that returned from the model that looks like this:

```
[dates] {
  [22] {
     [day] => [Friday]
     [type] => [weekday]
  }
  [23] {
     [day] => [Saturday]
     [type] => [Weekend]
  }
  [24] {
     [day] => [Sunday]
     [type] => [Weekend]
     [Holiday] => [Easter]
  }
}
```

This may be overkill or not. But I used this example to show that the MODEL is where you do all of this heavy lifting, not the controller or the view.

Next, build the view. I am not sure what it is in CodeIgniter, but in cake they are called Elements. These are snippets of view code that are available to any view (reusable view elements). So build a reusable view element that will take a date array, loop through it, and write the output in HTML. Notice how I can use the date array to format my view.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($dates as $date): ?>
  <li class="date <?php echo $dates[$date]['type']; ?>><?php echo $date; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Nice, clean, and concise. The advantage is if you ever want to change the look, you do not have to touch the controller. ;)

Now, for the controller. Put the code in the controller that calls the date array from the model, and passes it to the view. The idea is FAT model, SKINNY view.

```
function my_function() {
  // get code from model
  // set code for view
  // render view
}
```

While I haven't really "cleaned up" your code. I hope this gives you the guidance you were looking for on how to move the code around yourself so that a) it makes more sense to you and b) you can clean up the code in a way that will still conform to the MVC architecture you are striving for.

Good luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot; I'll go over my code again and rewrite it keeping your suggestions in mind. This makes a lot more sense now, and with those questions you put at the start I'll have some guidelines so I know where to put which code. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. The problem most of us have is that we manage M V & C so it is hard for us to keep the separation as we are writing the code. That's why I have to ask myself questions constantly.

Comment: Hi. Just letting you know that I rewrote my code using your suggestions and I have a much cleanier and 'easier' source code now. I'll also have to do a lot less 'cheating' to do what I want to do, compared to my previous code. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: So glad you commented! I often do not hear the results. It's so nice to hear that it helped you. Thank me by continuing to ask yourself those questions every time you get ready to code something. ;) Thanks for letting me know how everything went.

Comment: -1: controller deals with request, view handles response. There is nothing ambiguous bout the separation there

Comment: @tereško I'm not sure I follow your meaning and why you would -1 my response. The controller does not ALWAYS handle the request. The point I was making here was to give guidance on where code should be put given the question of the OP. In addition, I rolled back your changing of the question. This is about MVC patterns as they correspond to the PHP code. It has nothing to do with jQuery.